# Using Always Encrypted with EF Core and storing Master Key in Azure Key Vault

Tags: sql, azure-keyvault, .net-core-3.1, always-encrypted, ef-core-3.1

I have a .Net Core 3.1 project using EF Core to access data in an Azure SQL Database. I'm currently trying to implement the Always Encrypted feature on some sensitive column.

I successfully encrypted the column, storing the Master Key in Azure Key Vault where I created an App Registration with access to this key.

I used this video in order to achieve this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POLTjo7GpRc

I then was able to retrieve the Master Key in my c# code and launch an SQL query, a simple select from the encrypted table.

I could retrieve the encrypted column in clear text(decrypted), fine.

My question now, how can I configure EF Core to retrieve my Master Key in Azure Key Vault and return the decrypted value in my Entities? Sql query works but I don't know how to make it work with EF Core.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to my test, if you have configured Always Encrypted for your SQL Server with Azure key vault, please use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`  to implement EF core in your application.

For example

1. [Configure Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault?tabs=azure-powershell)
2. Create Azure AD application and configure access policy for the application in Azure key vault.
3. Configure application

   a. install sdk

   ```
    ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider" Version="1.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.1">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.7" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.1" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

   b. Create Modle

   ```
   public class Patient
   {

     public int PatientId { get; set; }
     public string SSN { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   c. create DbContext

   ```
   public class TestContext :DbContext
   {
      private static Boolean isInitialized;
      public  TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options)
      {
          if(! isInitialized) { InitializeAzureKeyVaultProvider(); isInitialized = true; }


      }


      public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>().ToTable("Patients");
      }

      private static string clientId = "the ad application appid";
      private static string clientSecret = "the ad application appSecret";
      private static ClientCredential _clientCredential;

      private static void  InitializeAzureKeyVaultProvider()
      {
          _clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

          SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider =
            new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(GetToken);

          Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> providers =
            new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>();

          providers.Add(SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, azureKeyVaultProvider);
          SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(providers);
      }

      private async static Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
      {
          var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
          AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, _clientCredential);

          if (result == null)
              throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the access token");
          return result.AccessToken;
      }
   }
   ```

   d. Register the DbContext. Add the following code in `Startup.cs`.
       
   `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
           services.AddControllersWithViews();
       }`

   e. add connectionString in appsettings.json

   ```
   {
   "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:<your server name>.database.windows.net,1433;
   Initial Catalog=<db name>;
   Persist Security Info=False;
   User ID=<user>;
   Password=<password>;
   Column Encryption Setting=enabled;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
   },
   ...
   ```

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/sqlclient-support-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Can you please tell me were do we get the `clientId` and `clientSecret` from? Couldn't find anything like that on Azure

Comment: how does it mix with writing stored procedures outside of Ef Core